# Reduce CPU frequency in battery mode automatically

Tags: cpu, cpufreq, frequency, xbacklight, cuttlefish

Is there any way to do that?

Something like xbacklight and Cuttlefish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can, using `tlp`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

ThinkPads require an additional:

```
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms
```

---

**what you can do with tlp ?**

1. Processor and Frequency Scaling(you can set whether your laptop runs in **powersaver or performance or ondemand mode**. also you can allow whether your processor uses **turbo boost** or not)
2. Undervolting
3. Runtime Power Management
4. Advanced Power Management(this feature controls how your various laptop component behave according to whether AC is connected or not)
5. HDD spin down
6. Automatic USB suspension

and many other power management settings. **tlp changes settings automatically according to power supply is plugged or not**.

**its better to read [tlp documentation](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html) before you use tlp, its written in simple language and step-by-step guide manner**

Comment: Thanks, Could you please help me to run tlp without password? When I run 'echo $USER' output is `vahid` then should I add `vahid ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/tlp` with `sudo vim /etc/sudoers`??

Comment: @Daniyal I use tlp by default settings. i.e. after installing, i make changes(settings)(`gksu gedit /etc/default/tlp`) by being root. tlp starts with system as a daemon with root privileges. you dont need to do anything related to password. if I am not clear please comment by being more specific

Comment: @Daniyal you need not to start it every time you start your system. if auto starts with root privileges. and your changes(settings)(which you make in `/etc/default/tlp`) are also loaded. read my above comment also

Comment: Thanks again, I want run tlp each time power supply plugged in or unplugged by Cuttlefish.

Comment: Final Thanks! my problem solved by `vahid ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/tlp bat` (without space)

Comment: @Daniyal tlp changes settings automatically according to  power supply is plugged or not. why use cuttlefish ?

Comment: OMG! I don't know this issue!! Thank you man...